vsftpd - Ensure Consistent 530 Responses
Trying to strengthens security by preventing username enumeration attacks and brute force, I'd like to standardize the 530 error code returned by vsftpd regardless of valid and invalid users, plus using fail2ban.
The vsftpd is running fine in production for years. Now willing to get a more secure environment for vsftpd setting up fail2ban. I realize that depending on the type of user trying to connect I receive a different 530 answer and behavior, therefore leaking if the user is valid or not.

Scenario 1 (user1):
Valid user declared in /etc/vsftpd.allowed_users & /etc/password (UNIX used for auth.)

$ ftp myftp.example.com
Connected to myftp.example.com.
220 Welcome FTP user.
Name (myftp.example.com:user1): user1
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
530 Login incorrect.
ftp: Login failed.


Scenario 2 (user2):
Invalid user not declared in /etc/vsftpd.allowed_users, it can be in /etc/password or not.

$ ftp myftp.example.com
Connected to myftp.example.com.
220 Welcome FTP user.
Name (myftp.example.com:user2): user2
530 Permission denied.
ftp: Login failed.

My vsftpd configuration sum-up (relevant IMO):
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users

I modified PAM and tried different options from the default /etc/pam.d/vsftpd, but the behavior is always the same and doesn't seems to be the point here (correct me if I'm wrong).
System logs shows pam when user1 is entering a bad password but nothing is shown when user2, thus fail2ban is unable to detect any attempt of connection with an invalid user.
Nov 27 17:01:33 myftp vsftpd[99999]: pam_unix(vsftpd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ftp ruser=fijipd rhost=::ffff:111.222.333.444 user=user1

My understanding would be first to get a consistent answer from the FTP prompt.
In a second time, I suppose having the first point resolved getting a working fail2ban behavior (from PAM errors or not).
Any clue appreciated,
thank you.
